# how do i write a test code to this? why does it give me back a typeerror?

Tags: python

the code is

```
def minutes_to_years_days(minutes):
    ydec=minutes/60/24/365
    y=int(ydec)
    ddec=(minutes-y*365*24*60)/60/24
    d=int(ddec)
    return (y,d)
```

when i wrote it as part of test code, i did this:

```
minutes= raw_input('Enter the number of minutes: ')
def minutes_to_years_days(minutes):
    ydec=minutes/60/24/365
    y=int(ydec)
    ddec=(minutes-y*365*24*60)/60/24
    d=int(ddec)
    sentence= '{} is approximately {} years and {} days.'.format(minutes,y,d)
print minutes_to_years_days()
```

but it told me that typeerror: minutes_to_years_days() takes exactly 1 argument and 0 given. 
im confused TT

Comment: You need to supply a value to the `minutes_to_years_days` function when you call it. You have `minutes` as a required parameter, but you aren't passing that value.

Comment: Your function takes an argument (`minutes`), yet at the bottom line, you call it wihout passing any argument.

Comment: even after you make that change ... it expects minutes to be numeric, but raw_input will give you str .... also its easier to go `minutes->hours;hours->days;days->years`

Comment: to test it better create list with examples - input data and expected result - and use `for` loop with `print minutes_to_years_days(example_data) == expected_result `. It is faster than using keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get typeerror because on the line:

```
print minutes_to_years_days()
```

you provide zero arguments for this function.

Replace this with i.e.

```
print minutes_to_years_days(2000)
```

and you will get some sort of result back from your function.

Comment: is it possible to write it as print minutes_to_years_days(raw_input)?